# Generating Tag cloud in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to generate a tag cloud using spring mvc.. i am trying to increase the font size of the tag based on the count.. can anyone give the step by step algorithm in order to automatically increase the font size based on counts..?  or is there any efficient way to do this ?..

Comment: There are a zillion examples of tag cloud code on the web--what have you tried? And how difficult is it, really, to pick a font size based on occurrence ratios?

Comment: Mr Newton, i am very new to the concept of spring mvc and tag cloud. i have found few algorithms on web but it says there are more than 1 algorithm which can be used so wanted to know the efficient one

Answer (score 0):

First count the font size for each element. Then just pass a map to your template (or other collection). Collection should have the item and font size. In your template just render item and pass the font size from it to the style argument in html

Thats basicly everything you need